# Windows sound enhancer software?

Tags: windows, software-rec, audio

I'm looking for software equalizer to enhance sound I get from my Windows 7 laptop, sadly Conexant High Definition Audio Driver does not provide such functionality. There are few solutions out there but I don't want to try them all, so what good equalizer can you recommend me?

EDIT: Just to make it clear: first, I listen to music through external set of decent speakers, not build-in laptop ones. Two, I'm looking for sort of system-wide, driver like plug which would enhance sound globally from any source, not specific player plugins (like proposed by mepher), nor player with equalizer function, I'm heavy Spotify user. By the way I used to have equalizer provided by Nvidia chipset driver on my old desktop pc and this makes world of difference in sound quality, why the hell this is not provided by system?

Comment: Before you rule the experience you are having as a problem with the sound card's equalization, try plugging in some good quality headphones and some good quality external speakers.  Laptop speakers suck, and it's not the sound card's fault.

Comment: @eleven81: I should state that I'm sane and I don't expect laptop speakers to produce good quality sound.

Comment: this has been asked a couple of times before. i don't think you'll find a global solution. if it was Realtek soundchip, they come with a mixer/control panel to enhance the sound globally.

Comment: @Molly: it's Conexant High Definition Audio (i wish it was high). I found equalizer [Blaze WebEQ](http://www.blazeaudio.com/products/webeq.html), but not sure if it works on Win7 and for $20 I would rather pay more and buy external Sound Blaster.

Comment: if they still exist, the website is from '07 ... and yes, if you want quality, go for an external solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [DFX Audio Enhancer](http://www.fxsound.com/dfx/index.php?vendor=0&subvendor=0&plus=0&refer=0).

> DFX enhances your music listening
>   experience by improving the sound
>   quality of MP3, Windows Media,
>   Internet radio and other music files.
>   With DFX you can transform the sound
>   of your PC into that of an expensive
>   stereo system placed in a perfectly
>   designed listening environment. Renew
>   stereo depth, boost your audio levels
>   and produce a deep, rich bass sound.

[image]

Comment: rather a player plugin, not a global solution :(

Comment: I just wrote down the one I know about and experienced...

Comment: that's quite OK, nobody's voting you down for that anyway. it just may not be what Resistance has in mind. :)

Comment: No worries.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are trying to do. If you are just listening to music through something like WMP, then you can use the equaliser in that. Of course that will only alter the sound from WMP.

If you want to equalise everything that passes through your speakers, then you are going to need some kind of stand-alone equaliser program. Personally im not aware of any such program, but im sure someone who does will post an answer here.

Comment: Most of media players provide equalizer, but I need global stand alone solution.

Comment: Have you checked for the latest drivers and software for your sound card? They may have added an equaliser, I know its not likey but its possible.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.claessonedwards.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56:bae-hw-reqs-info&catid=42:baetech&Itemid=72

Breakaway Audio Enhancer

Works as an audio "pipeline" and bypasses all volume controls

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.